# How to convert a StringBuffer to ASCII Code back into an integer

Tags: string, buffer, ascii, calculator

For a programming class, my teacher has requested I build a basic calculator. Though creating a CalculatorGUI is simple, my teacher wanted me to use a stringbuffer and ASCII code instead, for "good programming practice". My problem lies in converting my completed StringBuffer digit from the calculator inputs and turning it into ASCII code that I can solve it with. I'm sure the answer is simple, but I'm at a block at this portion of the code.

Thanks so much.

Comment: Could you post what you've tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

Strings have a getBytes method that takes a charset and returns a byte array in that charset.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#getBytes(java.nio.charset.Charset)

Something like:
`byte[] b = calcString.getBytes(Charsets.US_ASCII);`